# event listener is firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, dom-events

its a quiz app where clicking on replay button is supposed to restart the quiz and the given event listener code is used when the user selects an answer for question. it works completely fine during first time but when the quiz restarts, the event listener fires twice and if again replay is clicked , then the event listener for selecting correct option fires thrice

```js
let chosen = document.getElementsByClassName("option");
  console.log('options',chosen);
  for (let choosed of chosen) {
    choosed.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      clearInterval(myVar);
      clearInterval(counterLine);
      console.log("you have choosen");
      next.classList.add("next-show");
      next.classList.remove("next-hide");
      if (questionCount == 10) {
        finish.classList.add("next-show");
        finish.classList.remove("next-hide");
      }
      let choosenOption = e.target.className;
      choosenOption = choosenOption.substr(7, 14);
      let correctOption = arrayOFCorrectAnswers[questionCount - 1];
      if (correctOption.includes(choosenOption)) {
        colorGreen(e.target);
        score++;
      } else {
        colorRed(e.target);
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<div class="question-answer">
            <div class="question">
                <h2 id="question">Question Incoming.....</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="options-answers">
                <div class="option" id="option1">option1 </div>
                <div class="option" id="option2">option2</div>
                <div class="option" id="option3">option3</div>
                <div class="option" id="option4">option4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

this is the html

Comment: first remove listener then add listener on element  choosed.removeEventListener

Comment: I am not sure but after the first cycle , you need to remove the event listener for the Dom elements and reattach them. You are getting twice or thrice because you don't remove the initially render element and the number of clicks add up

Comment: I would suggest using an event listener on your `<select>` tag instead of the `<option>` tags. For instance the `change` event

Comment: Add the HTML so that we can discern whether there's a propagation problem.

Comment: @zer00ne I added the html

Comment: @Kerry and @ Sanjay Choudhary  your answers worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the OP example and couldn't understand it very well. I did notice that it is a quiz without any form controls (not even a `<button>`). If you are interacting with the user and require input from said user it would behoove you to use `<form>`, `<input>`, `<button>`, etc.

The demo below has:

- `init()` which wraps around all of the variables and functions acting as a closure. It passes 3 arrays.
- `init()` is ran only once. It will register the 'submit' event to the `<form>` and register the 'click' event to a `<button>`. It also runs `spawnQA()` which changes the text of the question and the 4 options.
- The options are `<input type='radio'>` and `<label>`

```js
const questions = ['Question 1', 'Question 2', 'Question 3', 'Question 4'];
const options = [
  ['1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4'],
  ['2.1', '2.2', '2.3', '2.4'],
  ['3.1', '3.2', '3.3', '3.4'],
  ['4.1', '4.2', '4.3', '4.4']
];
const answers = [1, 0, 3, 2];

const init = (questions, options, answers) => {
  const form = document.forms.QA;
  const io = form.elements;
  const Q = document.getElementById('question');
  const inst = document.querySelector('section');
  const list = document.querySelector('ol');
  const display = document.querySelector('.display');

  let count = parseInt(io.counter.value);
  let score = parseInt(io.correct.value);

  const endQuiz = () => {
    Q.textContent = "Quiz Completed";
    inst.classList.toggle('hide');
    list.classList.toggle('hide');
    io.btn.classList.toggle('hide');
    io.rst.classList.toggle('hide');
    display.textContent = `Score: ${score}`;
    return false;
  };

  const resetQuiz = event => {
    inst.classList.toggle('hide');
    list.classList.toggle('hide');
    io.btn.classList.toggle('hide');
    io.rst.classList.toggle('hide');
    count = 0;
    score = 0;
    spawnQA(questions, options, answers, count);
    form.reset();
  };

  const spawnQA = (questions, options, answers, count) => {
    if (count >= answers.length) {
      endQuiz();
      return false;
    }

    const opts = [...document.querySelectorAll('.option')];

    Q.textContent = `${count+1}. ${questions[count]}`;

    opts.forEach((label, index) => {
      label.textContent = options[count][index];
    });
    return false;
  };

  const nextQuestion = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const opts = [...io.options];
    for (let [idx, opt] of opts.entries()) {
      if (opt.checked) {
        score = answers[count] === idx ? ++score : score;
      }
    }
    count++;
    io.counter.value = count;
    io.correct.value = score;
    spawnQA(questions, options, answers, count);
    console.log('score: ' + score);
    console.log('count: ' + count);
  };

  form.onsubmit = nextQuestion;
  io.rst.onclick = resetQuiz;
  spawnQA(questions, options, answers, count);
};

init(questions, options, answers);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}

ol {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input,
label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}


/* SO Console Display - Right Side Column */

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 50% !important;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  font-variant: normal;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content: '';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<form id="QA">
  <input id='correct' type='hidden' value='0'>
  <input id='counter' type='hidden' value='0'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend id="question">Question Incoming.....</legend>

    <ol>
      <li>
        <input id='option1' name='options' type='radio'>
        <label for='option1' class='option'>Option 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id='option2' name='options' type='radio'>
        <label for='option2' class='option'>Option 2</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id='option3' name='options' type='radio'>
        <label for='option3' class='option'>Option 3</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id='option4' name='options' type='radio'>
        <label for='option4' class='option'>Option 4</label>
      </li>
    </ol>

    <section class='hide'>
      <p class='display'></p>
      <p>Click "Reset" to reset quiz.</p>
    </section>

  </fieldset>
  <button id='btn'>Next</button>
  <button id='rst' class='hide' type='button'>Reset</button>
</form>
```